# Remove following rows that are above or under by X amount from the current row['x']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am calculating correlations and the data frame I have needs to be filtered.

I am looking to remove the rows under the current row from the data frame that are above or under by X amount starting with the first row and looping through the dataframe all the way until the last row.

example:

df['y'] has the values 50,51,52,53,54,55,70,71,72,73,74,75
if X = 10 it would start at 50 and see 51,52,53,54,55 as within that 10+- range and delete the rows. 70 would stay as it is not within that range and the same test would start again at 70 where 71,72,73,74,75 and respective rows would be deleted

the filter if X=10 would thus leave us with the rows including 50,75 for df.

It would leave me with a clean dataframe that deletes the instances that are linked to the first instance of what is essentially the same observed period. I tried coding a loop to do that but I am left with the wrong result and desperate at this point. Hopefully someone can correct the mistake or point me in the right direction.

```
df6['index'] = df6.index
df6.sort_values('index')
boom = len(dataframe1.index)/3


#Taking initial comparison values from first row
c = df6.iloc[0]['index']
#Including first row in result
filters = [True]

#Skipping first row in comparisons
for index, row in df6.iloc[1:].iterrows():
    if  c-boom <= row['index'] <= c+boom:
        filters.append(False)
    else:
        filters.append(True)
        # Updating values to compare based on latest accepted row
        c = row['index']

df2 = df6.loc[filters].sort_values('correlation').drop('index', 1)
df2
```

[OUTPUT BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2tJt.png)

[OUTPUT AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDE3d.png)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, your main issue is to filter consecutive values within a threshold.

You can use a custom function for that that acts on a Series (=column) to return the list of valid indices:

```
def consecutive(s, threshold = 10):
    prev = float('-inf')
    idx = []
    for i, val in s.iteritems():
        if val-prev > threshold:
            idx.append(i)
            prev = val
    return idx
```

Example of use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': [50,51,52,53,54,55,70,71,72,73,74,75]})
df2 = df.loc[consecutive(df['y'])]
```

Output:

```
    y
0  50
6  70
```

##### variant

If you prefer the function to return a boolean indexer, here is a varient:

```
def consecutive(s, threshold = 10):
    prev = float('-inf')
    idx = [False]*len(s)
    for i, val in s.iteritems():
        if val-prev > threshold:
            idx[i] = True
            prev = val
    return idx
```

Comment: thank you it works, I added a variable that is 1/3 the length of the period I want to apply to test correlation with on the entire dataset. That way it remains adaptable to any type of dataset going forward.